# OWL to relational transformation tools

Tags: rdbms, owl, semantic-web, relational

I am starting to work with OWL using Protégé. It is all very intuitive for someone with a background on ontologies. With the onotology specified I would need to implement it as a relational schema in a DBMS. I have so far found references to two tools, none of which are usable in my case:

- An old [plug-in for Protégé](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/ConvertToDBScript) exists, but can only deal with mySQL.
- A article from the [International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications](https://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume7No11/Paper_2-OWLMap_Fully_Automatic_Mapping_of_Ontology.pdf) refers to a tool named OWLMap, but it is nowhere to be found (I wonder how this article was reviewed).

It is not difficult to use a OWL library to load a model into an OO language and then derive a relational schema from it. But if a tool or method already exists I would rather avoid developing something new.

Comment: This question was originally posted at [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), which succeeded a Q&A section at [semanticweb.org](https://www.semanticweb.org). However, at SO this question is out scope (requesting guidance on a tool). Instead of closing please direct this question to the appropriate site within the StackExchange multiverse.